# How to get the selected radio button value to display in the Size text input box?

Tags: radio-button

HTML code with radio buttons
Whichever option is chosen here should be shown in the input box below

```
`<div class="Choosesize">
      <details>
        <summary class="SelectionHeader"><span class="circleborder">3</span><span>Select your size</span></summary>
        <div class="SizeOptions">
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="3XL" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel" for="3XL" onclick="displaySize()">   Triple XL   </label>
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="2XL" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel" for="2XL" onclick="displaySize()">   Double XL   </label>
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="XL" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel" for="XL" onclick="displaySize()">    Extra Large </label>
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="L" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel" for="L" onclick="displaySize()"> Large   </label>
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="M" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel"  for="M" onclick="displaySize()">    Medium  </label>
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="S" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel"  for="S" onclick="displaySize()">    Small       </label>
          <input class="SizeInput" type="radio" name="size" id="XS" onclick="displaySize()">
          <label class="SizeLabel" for="XS" onclick="displaySize()">    Extra Small </label>
        </div>
      </details>
    </div>`
```

HTML code for input box
`<div class="CustomOption"> <input type="text" name="size" disabled value="Your size" id="YourSizeId"> </div>`

Javascript I've tried

```
 `function displaySize() {
  var SizeChecked = document.getElementsByName('size');

  for (i=0; i<SizeChecked.length; i++) {
    if (SizeChecked[i].checked)
document.getElementById("YourSizeId").innerHTML = SizeChecked[i].value;
 }
}`
```

[The text "Your size" should change to the text of whichever radio button is checked. Currently, it is not recognising this and nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUWUE.png)

Comment: Show the results you're getting, you're not showing the problem, just asking for an answer.

Comment: @MaxCascone Sorry max. I am new to this and dont know the proper way to go about using StackOverflow. 
Do you know why my code isnt working or why the logic isnt pulling how i anticipate it to?